# ADB SHELL INPUT TEXT Missing characters in result

Tags: android, node.js, adb

Occasionally, I am having trouble sending text to the emulator. It does not always write correctly what I have sent; it is as if it writes so quickly or reads so quickly that it does not finish writing the word

For example, if I write:

> Monkey77

sometimes it is written correctly and sometimes it shows me

> Mon

or any strange result but not the word Monkey.

I have been searching and documenting and find nothing that refers to this type of error. I have tried different android emulators and they all give me the same problem.

The command I'm using is: `adb -s ip:port  shell input text "Monkey77"`

I've tried this command: `adb -s ip:port  shell input keyboard text "Monkey77"` and I have the same problem.

Comment: I've got a script now that is swapping a letter occasionally...not 100% reproducible..but instead of "gmt.imelda.mills@collier.simulator.com" i'm getting "get.imelda.mills@collier.simulator.com" with adb shell input text gmt.imelda.mills@collier.simulator.com

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved it by sending character by character:

```bash
adbinp() {
    if [ "$1" = "-h" ] || [ "$1" = "--help" ]; then
        echo "Sends the given text to the connected Android device." >&2
        echo "Usage: adbinp [-h, --help] text ..." >&2
        echo '' >&2
        return 129
    fi
    echo "$*" | fold -w 1 | while read -r c; do
        test -n "$c" || c="%s"
        adb shell -n input text "\\$c"
    done
}
```

Spaces will result in zero length lines by `fold` and need to be replaced by `%s` to encode them properly for `adb shell`.

We also prepend any character with an escape sequence to make special characters like `#` work. In my testing it seems to affect only special characters, so things like `\n` will not result in new lines, but still print the character `n`. The escape sequence logic seem to be custom.

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same issue. When sending 'L739B43kfNiAn54' to an `EditText`, it receives 'L739B4k3fNiAn54' instead, with the '43k' sequence in the wrong order. The solution I've found is to send the characters one by one, possibly with a slight delay.

Answer (score -2):

#### I don't know why this happens to you, when I am trying to write input text monkey77 it works fine, however, try this and see if it will solve your problem:

```
adb -s ip:port shell input text $(echo "Monkey77")
```